# I have a list of the following structure and need to return data from it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The list is like this-

```
[(a,{1:True,2:False}),(b,{1:False,2:True})........]
```

Now I need to return the numbers which are true for one or more letter inputs.

Sample input-
a

Sample output-
1

Sample input-
a,b

Sample output-
1,2(since 1 is true for A and 2 is true for B I need to return both)

It is basically a list of tuples in which there are also dictionaries.

Comment: Please share what you tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "1-true" etc.?

Comment: it is not actually 1 in my list, in the place of 1 and 2 my list has CAM,CSR etc and many variables which have boolean values.  I have used the numbers and alphabets to make the example easy.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add sample input and example output to your question

Comment: added sample input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set up your initial data structure differently.
But let's roll with what you have.

An extended example list `l` could be:

```
>>> l = [('a', {1: True, 2: False}), ('b', {1: False, 2: True}), 
        ('c', {1: False, 2: False, 3: False}), 
        ('d', {1: True, 2: True, 3: False, 4: True})]
```

Under the assumption that all your tuples are 2-tuples, that can be turned into a dict:

```
>>> d = dict(l)
>>> d
{'a': {1: True, 2: False}, 'c': {1: False, 2: False, 3: False},
 'b': {1: False, 2: True}, 'd': {1: True, 2: True, 3: False, 4: True}}
```

Then, define the letters of interest:

```
letters = 'abcdef'
```

Note that `c` has only `False` values, while `e` and `f` don't even exist. All three should thus result in an empty list.

Now, we can obtain the results in a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [[key for key, value in d.get(letter, {}).items() if value] for letter in letters]
[[1], [2], [], [1, 2, 4], [], []]
```

In case you just want a single list of the numbers, flatten this nested list:

```
>>> result = [[key for key, value in d.get(letter, {}).items() if value] for letter in letters]
>>> [item for sublist in result for item in sublist]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 4]
```

And for unique numbers, make it a set:

```
>>> set([item for sublist in result for item in sublist])
set([1, 2, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension:

```
my_list = [('a',{1:True,2:False}),('b',{1:False,2:True}), ('b',{1:False,2:False}), ('a',{1:True,2:False})]
my_input = {'a', 'b'}

[k for t in my_list if t[0]  in my_input for k, v in t[1].items() if v]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 1]
```